# Setter and Getter for Java 2d array length

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I did a structured code of a  java project that involves a 2d array and now I am trying to make my code object oriented. I am trying to access the length of the 2d array but I am struggling.

I had this for my structured code:

*`private static char[][] environment = new char[0][];`*

and I kept using *`environment.length;`* inside the methods

but when I am trying to switch to OOP, I am having trouble accessing the length of the environment in different classes. Do I use a set and get like this:

```
 public static char[][] getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    public static void setEnvironment(char[][] environment) {
        MyClass.environment = environment;
    }
```

and then access the length like this:

```
MyClass.getEnvironment().length
```

Is this allowed? Is there any other way to do this? I am also having problems when i have an input for the 2d array.

I use this in the structured version:

```
if ( y<= environment[y].length - 1)
```

Am I allowed to do this in OOP:

```
if (y<= MyClass.getEnvironment().length - 1)
```

I do not know how to incorporate the y in the code above.

Comment: Static methods barely contribute towards object orientation. They behave more like procedural language.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll want to do is create methods that replace your original logic.

If you're using the length method on your `char[][]` like so,

`if (y <= environment[y].lenght - 1)`

you can encapsulate the behavior for reuse with something like this:

`public static int getEnvironmentLengthAt(int y) {
    return environment[y].length;
}`

I think `MyClass.getEnvironment().length` probably won't work because you're trying to return the length of a 2-dimensional array and your comparison is on a specific row within that 2-d array.

Without having more context, something like `MyClass.getEnvironment(y).lenght` might work better for you, but you'd have to have a method declaration like this,

`public static char[] getEnvironment(int y){ 
    return environment[y];
}`

to support the above method call.

Comment: So make different methods for the different cases?

Comment: Yeah, for cases where you'd like to encapsulate access to your data structures, i.e. any place you want to access your `char [][] environment` object